# node.js how to get the column value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been studying node.js and mongodb. I want to bring the specific db values​​. But is not easy for me. I want to get values that array in the Vidget.
I don't know how to implement.

my mongodb data

```
  {
    "Seq": 1,
    "UID": "kingnight99",
    "DBID": "yyyymmddhhmmss",
    "NAME": "name",
    "DESC": "desc",
    "Forms": [
              {
               "Seq": 1,
               "Name": "aaa",
               "Desc": "aaa",
               "Vidget": [
                           {
                             "Seq": 1,
                             "Vid": "ID",
                             "X": "x",
                             "Y": "y",
                             "W": "w",
                             "H": "h"
                            },
                          {
                            "Seq": 2,
                            "Vid": "ID",
                            "X": "x",
                            "Y": "y",
                            "W": "w",
                            "H": "h"
                          },
                          {
                           "Seq": 3,
                           "Vid": "ID",
                           "X": "x",
                           "Y": "y",
                           "W": "w",
                           "H": "h"
                          }
                       ]
               }
             ]     
   }
```

my node.js

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('vizboard', [ 'member', 'count','Dashboard' ]);
exports.checkData=function(req,res){
  console.log('check Dats json in');
  console.log('Forms Seq:'+req.param('seq'));
  db.Dashboard.find({
     "Forms":{"Seq":Number(req.param('seq'))}
 },function(error,result){
    if(error){
        console.log('error:'+error);
    }
    console.log('data':'+JSON.stringify(result));
}).Vidget;
}
```

result is null... i ask for some advice!

Comment: are you using mongoose driver?

Comment: @yaoxing i am using mongojs npm

Comment: hmm, not familiar with this driver. But if it's in mongo shell, I would write db.Dashboard.find({"Forms.Seq": 'value'}); Maybe you should try that.

Comment: @yaoxing T.T it is not work..

Comment: @yaoxing it is working in mongo shell but all the data is output in mongo shell i want to array values in vidget column

Comment: Just had a look at the mongojs doc. From what I'm understanding it should be db.Dashboard.find({"Forms.Seq": parseInt(req.param('seq'))}, function(err, result) {... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the result where it is returned to you:

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('vizboard', [ 'member', 'count', 'Dashboard' ]);
exports.checkData = function (req, res) {
    console.log('check Dats json in');
    console.log('Forms Seq:' + req.param('seq'));
    db.Dashboard.find({
        "Forms.Seq": Number(req.param('seq'))
    }, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error:' + error);
        }
        console.log('data:' + JSON.stringify(result));

        // here is your result, it's not accessible outside this function!

        result[0].Forms.forEach(function (form) {
            console.log('form Name=' + form.Name, form.Vidget);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: result aleardy is null..T.T i don't get data that array in Vidget

Comment: And in mongo-shell, what does `db.Dashboard.find({"Forms.Seq": 42})` return? Replace 42 with a value in your database.

Comment: Forms.Seq have only one value that number(1)

Comment: What does db.Dashboard.find({"Forms.Seq": 1}) return?

Comment: db.Dashboard.find({"Forms.Seq":1}) all data output!.

Comment: Can you prove that you're connecting to the right database with your node.js program? Edit your question and append the output of the console-log.

Comment: Give me your advice helped me to solve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

It is simply your query that is badly written, so its result is `null`:

```
{
    "Forms":{"Seq":Number(req.param('seq'))}
}
```

Your Forms field is an array (containing a single element), whose elements are JSON objects.

Hence, your query should be:

```
{
    "Forms": {
        $elemMatch: {"Seq": 1}
    }
}
```

More information about mongodb queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/